# Android Studio: Database created but no table created

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a simple database file with Android Studio. I've written the code like this and no errors were shown. I checked the `data/data/com.example.app/databases` file and there are three files: `Student.db`, `Student.db-shm`, `Student.db-wal` but no `Student.db-journal` like the tutorials in it. And when I try to open the `Student.db` with **DB Browser** no tables are created.

I have tried multiple syntaxes with the "CREATE TABLE" part but it didn't work.

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS"; 

    public Database(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY 
       KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

and activity will be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Database myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDb = new Database(this);

    }
}
```

Comment: try renaming your database because I believe it doesn't need a .db suffix . Maybe it is causing trouble. After that uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: Some tutorials say it needs .db some dont Im not sure :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @trpn39 Try this,

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userdata_table";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "country";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLENAME + " (" +
            KEY_STUID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_SUB1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            KEY_SUB2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            KEY_SUB3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            KEY_MARKS1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            KEY_MARKS2 + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            KEY_MARKS3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL"
            + ")";

      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

**Initialising in any activity**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

   databaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(this);

   //create method to store
   storeData();
}

 public void store(){

 //you need to implement getwritable database here
 ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            SQLiteDatabase db = 
     databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();   

 contentValues.put(SarathCityLocalDatabase.SUB_CATEGORY_LIST_ID, id);
                            contentValues.put(databaseHandler.COLUMN_ID, id);
                            contentValues.put(databaseHandler.COLUMN_NAME, name);
                            contentValues.put(databaseHandler.COLUMN_COUNTRY, county);
                            contentValues.put(databaseHandler.LOGO, logo);  

  //insert data in table

 db.insert(SarathCityLocalDatabase.public class DatabaseHandler extends 
SQLiteOpenHelper  {

 public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userdata_table";
 public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
 public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
 public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "country";


 public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

 String CREATE_TABLE, null, 
   contentValues);
   }

 }
```

Please let me know after you tried this

Comment: Here it is :( http://pasted.co/05835381. I still see no tables in the test.db file I dont know it seems like Im the only one with this problem

Comment: how do I implement the contentValues.put() method with my data, Im not sure what SarathCityLocalDatabase should be replaced with.

Comment: http://pasted.co/768db4c3 The Database class is exactly the same, I fixed the MainActivity like yours

Comment: the problem is fixed or not? @trpn39

Comment: content values are the values where you insert the data into database @trpn39

Comment: check my answer you need to insert the data in table @trpn39

Comment: Turns out I must have all three files in the folder in order to view the tables.. So I think there is nothing wrong with the code at all. Thank you very much for your help I will use your code for data insertion :D TYTY

Comment: Thank you.If it helps you please accept my answer and upvote it. So it will reach more people @trpn39

Comment: I need more than 15 reputations to upvote your post :(

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps. @trpn39 . Someone might get help from this.

Comment: Yes I did it I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Query syntax is like this for example:

```
 db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME + " (" +
                KEY_STUID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_SUB1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SUB2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SUB3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARKS1 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARKS2 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARKS3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL);"
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've tried multiple syntaxes including this one but it still doesnt work.

Comment: paste your full database class

Comment: http://pasted.co/347aee0c Here it is. My mainacitivity only has Database myDb=  new Database(this); Thank you!

Comment: change your database class name to MyDatabase , sometimes saved keywords create problem too.

Comment: I tried MyDatabaseHelper yesterday but let me try again. :( thank you

Comment: no problem , check this link too https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite
your code is right. or try to uninstall app then again install in your device , then check database created or not

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. What do you mean by uninstall app, Im just running by emulator haha

Comment: alright uninstall your app from emulator first , then clean your code then run again. by doing this old instance of your db will be deleted from memory

Comment: I created a whole new project and when I created the constructor for the Database class, it has these '@'androidx.annotation.Nullable before the parameters, I deleted them and now the app wont even run :(

Answer (score 0):

If you created your database without creating your table when running your app for the first time, it won't exist since onCreate() is called whenever the app is freshly installed.

You'll be able to call the onCreate() method in onUpgrade() by changing your database version like this:

```
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

**onUpgrade()** is called when the app is upgraded, launched **AND** when the database version is not the same.

Hope that it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed the DATA_BASE version and reload the app with the emulator. I have an add() function as well to test if the data is added in but still no tables in the Student.db file :(

Answer (score 0):

**Create a helper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper and override onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods**

```
    private static class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public MyHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME + " (" +
            id+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COL_2+ " TEXT," +
            COL_3+ " TEXT," +          
            COL_4+ " INTEGER);"
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I did :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is nothing wrong with the code. I must put all three files Student.db, Student.db-shm, Student.db-wal in one folder in order to open it with DB Browser. Thank you all for your help, I learned a lot :D